# Why isn't exponentiation in a prime order group a random function?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

Give a prime order group $\mathbb Z_p$, let's take a generator $g$ and raise it to $x$,
now, is $g^x$ a random number and indistinguishable from any other element in the group?

What am I missing?

Comment: Asymmetric crypto isn't my area. It seems like magic sometimes. Are you thinking DLP is hard therefore randomness? Being a one way function doesn't imply being a pseudorandom function. What about when you have small g and x values? Here is a link I saw years ago (that may be a useful learning aid or may be dangerously misleading for all I know)  (nor is it a blog I have followed so I can't endorse it) https://alicebob.cryptoland.net/visualizing-group-structure-with-colored-additionmultiplication-tables/

Comment: Way too many unknowns here. Define "random number", for starters.

Comment: @fkraiem I guess she/he means "uniformly distributed in $\mathbb{Z}_p$"...

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira Yeah, well, I am tired of having to guess what people mean when they are too lazy to write it themselves. This person is a regular offender, too.

Answer (score 1):

Fix prime $p$ and generator $g$ of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$.

If $x$ is a uniform random element of $\mathbb Z/(p - 1)\mathbb Z$, then $g^x$ is a uniform random element of $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$, because the function $x \mapsto g^x$ of $\mathbb Z/(p - 1)\mathbb Z$ to $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$ is a bijection.

(Here, strictly speaking, ‘uniform random element of $S$’ means ‘function $f$ from sample space $\Omega$ to $S$ such that $P(f^{-1}(x)) = P(\{\omega \in \Omega : f(\omega) = x\}) = 1/|S|$ for all $x \in S$’, and the composition $g^x$ means $\omega \mapsto g^{f(\omega)}$.)

There's no pseudorandom *function* here because that's an abbreviation for pseudorandom function *family*, which means a *keyed family of functions*.

Answer (score 1):

$F_g: x\mapsto F_g(x)=g^x$ is not a random function (more precisely, it not a member of a pseudo-random function family parametrized by $g$ ).

Problem is: for all $(g,x,y)$, it holds that $F_g(x+y)=F_g(x)\cdot F_g(y)$. And that property is both testable given a black box implementing $F_g$ , including for unknown $g$ ; and impossibly unlikely for a random function. It thus allows to build an extremely efficient distinguisher.

That property matters to use as a random number generator. For example, $F_g(x)$ for incremental $x$ (including unknown) does not yield random-like elements of the group: using $F_g(x)\cdot F_g(x+2)=F_g(x+1)\cdot F_g(x+1)$, three consecutive values are distinguishable; and with $g$ known that goes down to two.